# How to change the AES key of a specific column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a test table in which some columns are encrypted using an AES key, now I think of changing the AES key of those column?

I used the following query to set an AES key:

```
UPDATE test_encrypt SET first_name = AES_ENCRYPT(first_name, 'g50l2');
```

Now, I want the change the AES key, Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have encrypted the data using an AES key the data is encrypted (the point of using AES). The only way to change the key would be to decrypt the data with the old AES key and then re-encrypt the data using a new ASE key.

Some good [MySQL AES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) documentation.